# Sinon calls the original method, after stubbing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, sinon, stub

Trying to stub an ES6 import method. But sinon calls the original method.

```
    //utils.js
    export function getUser(name) {
       return name + " has been fetched";
    }
    //user.js

    import { getUser } from './utils.js';

    export default function printName() {
      return getUser("user");
    }

    //user.test.js
    import sinon from 'sinon';

    import * as utils from '../src/utils.js';

    import printName from '../src/user.js';

    const assert = require('assert');

    describe('print name', () => {

      it('should fetch and print the user name', async () => {

        let utilsStub = sinon.stub(utils, 'getUser');

        utilsStub.withArgs("user").returns("test");

        assert.equal("test", printName());
      });

    });
```

When calling a method inside the same module, it stubs properly, not sure if anything is wrong. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi,@Saranya! What do you mean exactly with "When calling a method inside the same class, it stubs properly"? 

I don't know if you have simplified your test, but you are not calling `utils.getUser` in your test after stubbing the method.

Comment: @mgarcia Sorry I meant the module, now its edited. And I have called utils.getUser with arguments test.

Comment: your code has multiple errors as it is in your question. Is this the real code you are trying to test?

In your *fetch.test.js* you are importing your `utils` module as *utils* but you are mocking `Utils` in the `beforeEach` hook. Your `.to.equal` is appended after the call to `fetch()` but should be called after the call to `expect`.

Furthermore, if you are mocking your `getUser` method to return the same thing that the original method returns, how do you know that you are not stubbing the method?

Comment: Edited my code, I have tested it as well, and it doesnt work. I was having problem with ES6 Class importing a module, so I directly posted a sample code before.

Comment: I am testing the code you posted and it works for me. What do you mean by "it doesnt work"? Are you seeing any errors? If so, what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: I get assertion error AssertionError: 'test' == 'user has been fetched', because it calls the original function. So, are you saying that it doesnt call the original and the test passes for you?

Comment: Yes. You can see it working in the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-meninsky-0pk87).

Comment: The test passes for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me:

`utils.ts`:

```js
export function getUser(name) {
  return name + " has been fetched";
}
```

`user.ts`:

```js
import { getUser } from "./utils";

export default function printName() {
  return getUser("user");
}
```

`user.test.ts`:

```js
import sinon from "sinon";
import * as utils from "./utils";
import printName from "./user";

const assert = require("assert");

describe("print name", () => {
  it("should fetch and print the user name", async () => {
    let utilsStub = sinon.stub(utils, "getUser");
    utilsStub.withArgs("user").returns("test");
    assert.equal("test", printName());
  });
});
```

Unit test result with coverage report:

```sh
  print name
    ✓ should fetch and print the user name


  1 passing (10ms)

--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File          |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files     |    93.33 |      100 |       75 |    92.86 |                   |
 user.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 user.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 utils.ts     |       50 |      100 |        0 |       50 |                 2 |
--------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/56482038